# Erro em procedure "Must declare the scalar variable"

Tags: sql-server, procedure

Quando executo a seguinte Procedure, o SQLServer dá o erro:

> erro Must declare the scalar variable "@VDIAPARALISADO".

Procedure:

```
BEGIN
SELECT @VDIAPARALISADO = COUNT(F.DATA)
FROM ED_FERIADO F
WHERE F.EDEMPRESA_ID = @PEDEMPRESA_ID
    AND F.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @PGMUNICIPIO_ID
    AND F.SECRETARIA_ID = @PSECRETARIA_ID
    AND F.ANO = @PANO
    AND F.TIPO IN ('6')
    AND F.DATA BETWEEN @DT_INICIO
        AND @DT_FIM
    AND F.DATA NOT IN (
        SELECT C.DATA
        FROM ED_CALENDAR C
        WHERE F.EDEMPRESA_ID = @PEDEMPRESA_ID
            AND F.GMUNICIPIO_ID = @PGMUNICIPIO_ID
            AND F.SECRETARIA_ID = @PSECRETARIA_ID
            AND F.ANO = @PANO
            AND F.DATA BETWEEN @DT_INICIO
                AND @DT_FIM
            AND C.TIPO_CALEN = @VTIPO_CALENDARIO
        )

            END
```

Comment: Não acho que deve ser fechada, não é um erro de digitação, mas sim uma falta de declaração de variável, pode acontecer a outras pessoas.

Answer (score 2):

Faltou adicionar no início

```
DECLARE @VDIAPARALISADO INT
```

Comment: já está declarada mas eu declarei como: `DECLARE @VDIAPARALISADO NUMERIC = 0`

Answer (score 0):

Você está tentando passar um conjunto de registros para uma única variável. A variável @VDIAPARALISADO espera um valor Scalar, ou seja, um único valor.

Answer (score -1):

```
DECLARE @VARIAVEL TIPO(TAM)
SET @VARIAVEL = VALOR (SE ELA FOR RECEBER UM VALOR)
```