# Erro em query parametrizada: Must declare scalar variable

Tags: c#, sql

Estou ciente da existência dessa pergunta: [Erro em procedure "Must declare the scalar variable"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/38349/erro-em-procedure-must-declare-the-scalar-variable)

Mas ela não resolve meu problema. Minha situação é a seguinte:

Tenho uma query sql comum:

```
select id from USUARIOS where login = @txtlogin and password = @txtpassword
```

Esse é o meu objeto `SqlCommand`:

```
conn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString);
 conn.Open();
var com = new SqlCommand(command, conn);
```

Crio o `SqlCommand`, a conexão é aberta normalmente, e eu adiciono os parâmetros assim:

```
SqlParameter param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@txtlogin";
param.Value = "teste";
//command é o meu SqlCommand devidamente inicializado
command.Parameters.Add(param);

param = new SqlParameter();
param.ParameterName = "@txtsenha";
param.Value = "teste";
//command é o meu SqlCommand devidamente inicializado
command.Parameters.Add(param);
```

Porém, ao executar a query, ele me dá o erro:

> Must declare the scalar variable @txtlogin

O que eu posso estar fazendo errado?

Comment: Faça um [mcve], faltando trechos importantes fica difícil responder.

Answer (score 1):

Existem duas possibilidades aqui:

- **Você usa Stored Procedures?** Em caso positivo, altere o valor da propriedade [`CommandType`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.commandtype(v=vs.110).aspx) do seu `SqlCommand` para `CommandType.StoredProcedure`. Assim:

```
com.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
```

- **Você não usa Stored Procedures?** Nesse caso, você precisa declarar cada variável que for usar na query que vai passar ao banco. Sua query completa ficaria assim:

```
DECLARE @txtlogin nvarchar(20), @txtsenha nvarchar(20)
SELECT id FROM USUARIOS WHERE login = @txtlogin AND password = @txtpassword
```